# How to get specific keys from a json file with php

Tags: php, arrays, json

So I have this json file

```
[
    {
        "var1": "6",
        "var2": "13",
        "var3": "17"
    },
    {
        "var1": "9",
        "var2": "11",
        "var3": "6"
    }
]
```

How can I get only the values of `var2` which are `13` and `11`?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `json_decode` alongside `array_column`, no need for unnecessary loops.

```
array_column(json_decode($json_string, true), 'var2'); // [13, 11]
```

For `array_column` the first argument is the array, second argument being the key you want to access.

`json_decode` the first argument is a string - your json. The second argument tells it to return an array and not `stdClass`.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php

Comment: No answer supporting those not fortunate enough to have PHP>=5.5?;) +1 for use of `json_encode`

Answer (score 1):

use json_decode()

```
$json = '[{    "var1": "6",    "var2": "13",    "var3": "17"},{    "var1": "9",    "var2": "11",    "var3": "6"}];'
$array = json_decode ($json, true);
$values = [];
foreach ($array as $ar) {
    $values[] = $ar['var2'];
}
var_dump($values);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`json_decode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) function, then use [`foreach`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) to get the values you want

```
$data = json_decode("your.json");

foreach ($data as $obj) {
    print $obj->var2;
}
```

[`json_decode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) let you to choose the data format to be retrieved *(object or associative array)*, if you prefer associative array style, just pass **true** as second parameter to `json_decode`

```
$data = json_decode("your.json", true);

foreach ($data as $obj) {
    print $obj['var2'];
}
```